# Error: Command failed: platform-tools/adb -s DEVICEID shell getprop

Tags: adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm using Ionic 4, Cordova 9, Nodejs 10.16, npm 6.9 and I would like to run the app on my device.
I just reinstalled Android Studio to the latest version and I got an error when using the run command:

**Command**

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

**Error** (DEVICEID - My Device ID)

```
Error: Command failed: P:\Simplifiedpath\platform-tools/adb -s DEVICEID shell getprop
```

When using *--verbose*, I get those details:

```
ionic:lib:shell Error in subprocess stdout pipe: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:248:12) at Object.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5) at Readable.write (C:\Simplifiedpath\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\stream-combiner2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:85
```

What's the point about this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after update sdk/platform-tools to version 29, i have the same error, to resolve:

Open Android Studio, and go to File>Settings>Android SDK on tab "SDK Tools" and uncheck 
"Android SDK Platform-Tools 29" and click "Apply" to uninstall platform-tools

Then. download platform-tools 28 from this link
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip
uncompress "platform-tools" under sdk directory, for example: "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"

to check if good, see File>Settings>Android SDK on tab "SDK Tools", now look like the image

[image]